# I can't use two operator in predicatewithformat in same time

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, nspredicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[cd] %@ AND (NOT (SELF MATCHES[cd] %@))", [NSString stringWithFormat: @".*\\b%@.*", string],[NSString stringWithFormat: @".*\\[\\b%@.*", string]];
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: you can definitely use two conditions in the same nspredicate. what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to use AND, NOT operator in same line. how to use that one. Ex: (a) AND (NOT(a)).

Answer (score 0):

try with subquery function it's helpful you

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"(add == %@) AND (SUBQUERY(subs, $x, $x.numbervalue == %@ or $x.numbervalue == %@).@count > 0)", @"add",number1, number2];
```

Another:

AND & OR can be used in predicate format strings to create compound `predicates`. However, the same can be accomplished using an `NSCompoundPredicate`.

For example, the following predicates are equivalent:

```
[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age > 25"], [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName = %@", @"Raja"]]];

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(age > 25) AND (firstName = %@)", @"Raja"];
```

Source: [Mattt Thompson](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a string like this "Raj Kumar [Mobile], Ram kumar [Home]". When i searching a character "H" it's show "Ram kumar [Home]". How to avoid this. I want to search only Firstname & Lastname 1st character. please help me.